# Back and Sync App data to dropBox

Tags: android, ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have an app which is on 3 platforms, iOS, android and windows phone. I was thinking of giving user an option to backup and sync there app data to/from dropBox.

I went through dropbox site, and I have few doubts which I am going to discuss below

DropBox has two apis
a)Sync API
b)Core API,

Now, what I have understood from the documentation on their site

Sync API, sync app data to users dropbox account , read/write is taken care by dropbox.

In CoreAPI, we have to initiate the calls to read/write.

But in both cases the appData is stored on users dropbox account.

Is there anyway, that I can access what user has saved to dropBox.(It will be helpful for analytics).

Instead of saving to users dropbox account can it be saved to a single account which I will create?

As I have my app for all the three platforms, so how the data will be managed

For ex. if the user is using an andriod app and he has backed up his data to dropBox, later he plans to shift to an iphone and wants to sync his app data. How it will be possible?

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Hi friends, can anyone guide me in this regard.

Comment: i think you may try having same Data model for all the 3 platforms.. Only that might help you in this case ..

Comment: Can you please elaborate bala?

Comment: this is upto my knowledge ,1. so if you have a same json database for all 3 platforms , it will be easy to parse in all 3 platforms.

Comment: 2. try using sqlite in all the platforms , like use SQLITE instead of COREDATA in iOS and don't know about window's database
So in that way all the 3 platforms will be having the same datamodel and table names..

Comment: Thanks bala, I was thinking of either JSON or SQLITE, but can we use it with sync API or coreAPI or we have to create our own methods using REST API. Any snippet how this should be done

Comment: Yes .. You can use both API,no prob with it.. anyway Happy coding..